# Reusable D3 chart in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, d3.js

I am new to this and still learning, so I am struggling a bit on this one.

GOAL: I want to create reusable chart in services.ts meaning I just want to pass parameters to get the chart.  I managed to create simple bar chart, but it was not reusable, especially when it comes to x and y axis and values. Json structure should be passed e.g. ({cluster:name1, value:1},{cluster:name2, value:7}). Then in the component would be easy to to just add parameters.

ISSUE: Passing param currently fails. Usually fails with type is not assignable to provided type, below

> Argument of type '(string | number | undefined)[]' is not assignable
> to parameter of type 'Iterable'.   The types returned by
> 'Symbol.iterator.next(...)' are incompatible between these types.
> Type 'IteratorResult<string | number | undefined, any>' is not assignable to type 'IteratorResult<NumberValue, any>'.
> Type 'IteratorYieldResult<string | number | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'IteratorResult<NumberValue, any>'.
> Type 'IteratorYieldResult<string | number | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'IteratorYieldResult'.
> Type 'string | number | undefined' is not assignable to type 'NumberValue'.
> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'NumberValue'.

CODE (visuals.services.ts):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as d3 from 'd3';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
    export class Visuals {
     
    
      BarChart(
        margin: number,
        domSelector: string,
        colour: string,
        dataAdd: any,
        barValues: string,
        barName: string
      ) {
        var svgBar = undefined;
    
        width = 550 - margin * 2;
        height = 200 - margin * 2;
    
        svgBar = d3
          .select(domSelector)
          .append('svg')
          .attr('width', width + margin * 2)
          .attr('height', height + margin * 2)
          .append('g')
          .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin + ',' + margin + ')');
    
    
        var x = d3
          .scaleBand()
          .range([0, width])
          .domain(dataAdd.map((d: any) => d[barName])) //above error
          .padding(0.2);
    
    
        svgBar
          .append('g')
          .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
          .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
          .selectAll('text')
          .attr('transform', 'translate(-10,0)')
          .style('text-anchor', 'middle')
          .style('font-size', 7);
    
        var y = d3
          .scaleLinear()
          .domain([0, d3.max(dataAdd, (d) => d[barValues])]) 
    
        svgBar.append('g').call(d3.axisLeft(y));
    
        svgBar
          .selectAll('bars')
          .data(dataAdd)
          .enter()
          .append('rect')
          .attr('x', (d: any) => x(d[barName])) //and similar here
          .attr('y', (d: any) => y(d[barValues]))
          .attr('width', x.bandwidth())
          .attr('height', (d: any) => height - y(d[barValues]))
          .attr('fill', colour);
      }
```

CODE (viz-comp.component.ts):

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataFetch } from '../datafetch.service';//another service to get the data
import { Visuals } from '../visuals.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-data-viz',
  templateUrl: './data-viz.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./data-viz.component.css'],
  providers: [DataFetch, Visuals],
})
export class DataVizComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private datafetch: DataFetch,
    private dataviz: Visuals
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    let br = new DatavizService();
    br.BarChart(
      20,
      '#barChart',
      '#121926',
      this.datafetch.Clusters,
      'count',
      'cluster'
    );
    console.log(this.datafetch.Clusters);
  }
}
```

Comment: I attempted to recreate your issue [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/bzi2lwSwNPGVkhoI).  The only thing I had to fix is the missing `var` or `let` keywords on your `width` and `height` declaration.  Can you update your question with how you are calling your method to make it fail?

Comment: @Mark I added the code for component